# Mouseleave glitch

Tags: javascript, mouseenter, mouseleave

I have a number of moving html elements (actually hrefs) with IDs such as #s1, #s2 etc. Each time I am hovering over one of them, I want some of the others to disappear. @AndrzejGorgoń helped me obtaining this by using JS. 
This is an extract of my html :

```
<div id=generalMap>

<a href="donner.html" class=S id=s0 data-hide-on-hover="2,6,7" data-hide-enable >Donner</a>
<a href="benevoles.html" class=S id=s1 data-hide-on-hover="2,3" data-hide-enable >Bénévoles</a>
<a href="tentatives.html" class=S id=s2 data-hide-on-hover="1,3,5" data-hide-enable >Tentatives</a>
<a href="belgium+kitchen.html" class=S id=s3 data-hide-on-hover="0,5,6" data-hide-enable >Belgium Kitchen</a>
etc.
```

And here is the JS coding how to get some of them appearing:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-hide-enable]');

elements.forEach(function(element) {

// add on hover effects
element.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(element) {
    var elementsIdsToHide = element.target.getAttribute("data-hide-on-hover").trim().split(',');

    var cssSelector = elementsIdsToHide.map(function(s) {
        return "#s" + s;
    });

    var elementsToHide = document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector.join(","));

    console.log(elementsToHide);

    elementsToHide.forEach(function(elemToHide) {
        elemToHide.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0")
    });

})

element.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(element) {
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll("[id^='s']"));
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='s']");

    elements.forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.setAttribute("style","opacity: 1");
    });
} )
```

})

However there is a gap when my mouse is leaving, in which all the elements are glitching (disappearing for 1/2 second).

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove gaps between elements. Here you have one of many ways how you can achieve this.

```
#generalMap {
    display: flex;
}

.S {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eqr1fxwL/

I put border on purpose to show that there is no gaps between elements.

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know about Flexbox ! Doesn't work either though. My actual HTML elements are floating around according to an array, so there has to be space between the boxes anyways. I am now trying to learn how to formulate something like boolean value true or false for mouseenter, instead of EventListener, what do you think?

Comment: Can you show me (some screenshoot) what do you want to achieve? Maybe I can help :)

Comment: Here we go ! (sorry, took some time cause I can't use the forum to show you) : go to      http://tinypic.com/r/besh91/9

Comment: As you see this is a kind of map where each title floats around. They are moving according to an array. On hovering over each one, the other titles non related to its subject disappears.

Comment: So... what about this idea:
hiding elements on mouseenter. And change the hidden elements on another mouseenter?

Comment: Do you mean putting the hidden elements to none when mouseentering the flex container?

Comment: I meant this:
1) when entering to element hidden what needs to hidden.
2) After mouse leave do nothing.
3) When entering again then computer what remains hidden, show what needs to be showed, hidden elements thats not hidden again.

Comment: But I would like to show all the elements when the mouse is not on a box. It should be a mouseenter selecting all the space around the boxes, but difficult because they are moving.Your first code is good but I still don't know why it is flashing, there has to be an answer why they all disappear quickly like this

Comment: It depends also on the computer I think and how fast are you moving from one element to another. If you leave element, then mouseleave event is firing and then all elements are showing. When enter another element, the mouseenter event is firing and then elements that need to be hide are hiding. While I write this message I thank that the function you need to add is debounce function. This is a function that delay/cancel execution of event to execute this function with newer data, I can show you my idea later on JSFiddle and I think this is the solution you need.

Comment: Hi Andrzej, guess what? I solved the problem and it was amazingly simple. Just had to suppress the elements' padding !!! Thanks a million for you help and have a good evening :)

Comment: Good to hear that : )